# How to only see a land mask of a whole area, inside just the raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, masking

I have a land mask that covers a larger area, but which I only need to see inside my RADARSAT image.

Here you can see the image with the land mask, but it is also covering an extent outside the image. I would like it so it is only in the image?

[image]

Is there a function on QGIS that can do this? Not to mention the land mask uses a lot of CPU on its own so I have to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `extract by extent` tool.

First input is you vector layer, then to the right of the "extent" field hit the dropdown menu and choose your raster layer.

If necessary, save your output to a file.